# Flash CS5.5: Play video on iPad?

Tags: flash, ipad, video

Has anyone succeeded in getting video to play in Flash published for the iPad?  I have tried using both the Video and StageVideo classes, but even though they test successfully in the Flash IDE, they do not work on the iPad.  I am using CS5.5.

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried so far?  This has been flagged as "off-topic" but I suspect it is a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved playing video in iPhone and iPad, follow the following steps:

You can use ordinary FLVPlayback

1. Keep videos and `.fla` file together.
2. Import the `FLVPlayback` component to stage and delete it in order to get the skin.
3. Add the following code in the first frame script (formats I used: `.flv`, `.mov`, `.mp4`):

---

```
import fl.video.*; 
var myVideo:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback(); 
myVideo.source = "video.flv"; 
myVideo.skin = "SkinOverPlayStopSeekFullVol.swf"; 
myVideo.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, completePlay); 
function completePlay(e:VideoEvent):void {
myVideo.alpha=0.2;
```

Important to keep in mind:

- While publishing the file, add the video files.
- For testing, add the video files, not the folder containing the video files and in source of the video player add just `filename.extension`.

Comment: This does not work.  I get a ton of errors, starting with this:  

NetConnection.connect cannot be called from a netStatus event handler.
 at flash.net::NetConnection/connect()
 at fl.video::NCManager/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::connectHTTP()
 at fl.video::NCManager/connectToURL()
 at fl.video::VideoPlayer/http://www.adobe.com/2007/flash/flvplayback/internal::_load()
 at fl.video::VideoPlayer/load()
 at fl.video::FLVPlayback/doContentPathConnect()
 at fl.video::FLVPlayback/set source()

Answer (score 0):

you can't load an external swf that contains code in ios unless you use a loadercontext and that's not possible with an flvplayback skin.

to remedy, don't use a skin and create custom controls, if needed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?